# How to use TokenAuthentication in mobile apps?

Tags: token, mobile-app

I'm working on a mobile application, using django rest-framework as backend, and I'd like to archive the maximum security possible.
Now when the user log-in with email and password I generate a token, Token Authentication from rest_framework (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) and I save it on the local storage of the application, and then when I use it to make requests.

A rest_framework token sample is like this 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b (40 characters).
Do I need to:

1. increase the number of characters?
2. update the token every certain time?

Feel free to link me all possible solutions.
Thank you

Comment: You might want a refresh token. And also maximum security always comes at the cost of minimum usability/comfort.

Comment: You can use OIDC. On each login, your identity provider will issue OIDC token which you store at client side. On each request, your backend service will make token introspection request to the identity provider to validate the token and to retrieve userinfo about the token.

Comment: But every time the token is generated I need to save it on database?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: My question is how to handle the use authentication using token in mobile apps. But I'd like to handle it as best as possibile.

Comment: If you use OIDC, you don't have to save the token in database.

Comment: thank you, can you link me some good articles about it?

Comment: [Best Django OIDC Package](https://number1.co.za/best-django-openidc-package/).